# редактирование сообщения ботом, отправленное им же в чат

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

почему при вызове функции

```
bot.edit_message_text(chatId, id_mes, result)
```

где `id_mes` id сообщения бота которое нужно редактировать через определенный промежуток времени вываливается ошибка

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}']
```

а если просто пишу

```
bot.send_message(chatId, result)
```

то сообщения в чат отправляются

Comment: У вас же в ошибке написано ```chat not found```

Comment: @Nobody я чуть изменил вопрос. Я понимаю что не находит чат, но если просто отправлять сообщения то все работает

Comment: Кажется у вас неправильный порядок параметров. Там текст должен быть на 1м месте (судя по документации)

Comment: @Nobody можно ссылку?

Comment: Там два метода есть, посмотрите оба https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=edit_message_text&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: @Nobody помогло когда дописал `chat_id=chatId` . Спасибо.

Comment: @Вадим, скажите, какую бибилтотеку конкретно вы используете? PyTelegramBotAPI или PythonTelegramBot? Это две совсем разных библиотек

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать `bot.edit_message_text("Текст", chat_id = <chat_id>, message_id = <message_id>)`